# Prove the commutativity property of addition of natural numbers by induction

Tags: induction, natural-numbers

the background I'm allowed to deal with to solve this problem is as follows:

Definition of +:
\begin{equation} m+0=m\quad \text{for all}\quad m \in \mathbb{N} \\
m+(k+1) = (m+k)+1 
\end{equation}
in conjunction with the induction property of $\mathbb{N}$. In a previous task I showed that $ 0+m=m \quad \forall \, m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Task: Prove $m+n=n+m$ by induction on $n$.

Now, it follows directly that $0+m=m=m+0$. With the assumption that $k+m=m+k$ for a $k\in\mathbb{N}$, it can be deduced:
\begin{eqnarray}
m+(k+1) & = & (m+k)+1\quad \text{by def. of}+\\
& = & (k+m) + 1\quad \text{with assumption}\\
& = & k + (m+1)\quad \text{by def. of}+.
\end{eqnarray}
Here, it looks to me that the true base step would be $m+1 = 1+m$, because then it would be possible to bring the proof straight to an end. But I tried hard to hack this last nut without any results. Is there anybody who could help me with this? Or maybe there is a completely different way to come up with the proof requested?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: if you are proving commutativity you can't start with $m+0=m=0+m$.  You're base case has to be a member of you index set, in this case $\mathbb{N}$.  I believe you are right to start with $n=1$.  Maybe you just say, by the definition of a number, $m=\sum_{k=1}^m{1}$?  Then $$m+1=\sum_{k+1}^{m}{1}+1=\sum_{k+1}^{m+1}{1}=1+\sum_{k+1}^{m}{1}=1+m$$

Comment: Also, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297609/how-to-prove-that-is-commutative-on-the-natural-numbers?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok folks, @Eleven-Eleven figured it out. The definition of $\mathbb{N}$ that I use is:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{N}\, \text{is the closure of the set} \{0\}\,\text{under}\,\it{successor}.
\end{equation}
This is, I think, basically the same definition as in the comment. Now let $m>0$ be the successor of $k$:
\begin{equation}
m=k+1.
\end{equation}
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
1+m&=&1+(k+1)\\
&=&(1+k)+1\quad \text{by def. of}+\\
&=&m+1.
\end{eqnarray}
With this, starting from the last manipulation in my question:
\begin{eqnarray}
m+(k+1)&=&k+(m+1)\\
&=&k+(1+m)\\
&=&(k+1)+m.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: '1+m===1+(k+1)(1+k)+1by def. of+m+1.' I disagree; you are assuming that k+1=1+k which is what you are trying to prove. you need an inductive step.

Comment: @user288453 This solution seems valid to me. By the definition of +, `m+(k+1)=(m+k)+1`, then for `m=1` you have `1+(k+1)=(1+k)+1`. He is not assuming `k+1=1+k` (what he is trying to prove).

Comment: @user288453: you are partly right, in saying that I assume:$ k+1 = m = 1 + k$. I took that knowledge from the comment of Eleven-Eleven, that's what I meant by confirming that I use the definition that he assumes. Of course I could have incorporated that into my answer to have more clear or complete.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply missing the last step:

\begin{align*}
m+(k+1)&=(m+k)+1 \\
       &=(k+m)+1\\
       &=k+(1+m)\\
       &=(k+1)+m
\end{align*}

So you proved your inductive step.

Comment: Hi dadexix86, thank you for your reply. While scratching my head about your answer, I noticed a serious typo in my question, more specific: in the last of the manipulations. It was late here last night. I corrected it and appologize. What I am missing to bring the proof to an end, is the property $m+1=1+m$. If this was valid, the proof would finish exactly as you proposed. Unfortunately I cannot find a proof for this base step of my induction.